# Preselect value in Struts <s:select> tag?

Tags: java, forms, struts2, struts, struts-tags

I have this Struts tag:

```html
<s:select name="country.id" 
          list="countries"  
          listValue="name" 
          listKey="id"
          headerValue="Select Country"
          headerKey=""
          label="Country" />
```

which outputs the following HTML code:

```html
<select name="country.id" tabindex="12" id="registration_country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">United States</option>
    <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="3">Albania</option>
    <option value="4">Algeria</option>
    ...
    <option value="192">Zambia</option>
    <option value="193">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

How do I specify that I want, for example, "Albania" to be preselected in the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `value` attribute in the `s:select` tag:

```
<s:select name="country.id" 
list="countries"  
listValue="name" 
listKey="id"
headerValue="Select Country"
headerKey=""
label="Country"
value="3" />
```

Comment: This do not work for me. Both value I have compare eventhough s:select not selecting the option. M bit new to struts. Please advice other check points. M using struts 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
headerKey="3"
```